# Galaxy S Blaze 4G not working with adb on Linux

Tags: android, linux, usb, adb, galaxy

I am having trouble getting my Samsung Galaxy S Blaze 4G to work with adb on Ubuntu 12.04.  When I do `adb devices` nothing is listed.

I have a message in dmesg like:
"usb can't set config #1, error -71"
(I've also received an "error -110" sometimes too)

I moved it to various USB ports, both built into the motherboard and via a PCI USB 2.0 card with no success.

I have an `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` that I created, ran the following commands, unplugged and replugged the USB cable on my phone:

```
sudo services udev restart
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

If I run `lsusb` I see the device listed, the phone has the USB icon in the notification area, and USB debugging is set in the developer options.

It used to work when I had the 2.3.3 firmware, but I recently upgraded to ICS 4.0.4.  And I also reinstalled Ubuntu on a new SSD I bought, but the /home is untouched and on my existing HDD.

Any ideas on what is wrong now and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you paste your udev rules?

Comment: did you enable the developer options?

Comment: It turned out to be the stupid USB cable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else seeing this issue... the USB cable turned out to be the culprit.